# rails aborted! LoadError: Could not open library 'libseabolt17'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'd like to have my Rails application connect to a Neo4j database (Neo4j community server):

https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Setup.html

I've installed this driver:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-ruby-driver

At this point it's impossible to run `bin/setup` or rake; the problem is:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'libseabolt17': libseabolt17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libseabolt17.so': libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Seabolt can be found at https://github.com/neo4j-drivers/seabolt, but it appears that libssl.so.10 requires an old compat-openssl10 RPM which is long obsolete. Even if I could find one I can install, it doens't seem particularly good to have to rely on such old libraries.

Am I missing something here? Is there any means to be able to connect to the running Neo4j server (systemctl status says: Bolt enabled on localhost:9687)?